# Creating detail view of doors in Revit api

Tags: revit-api, revit

How to create detail view in Revit of specific door using Revit API( external command)? For now I managed to  create DetailView, but when I open in Revit that view it is not what I expected(see images: [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipUPz.png) , [what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqJuV.png)).

Here is the code:

```
IEnumerable<ViewFamilyType> viewFamilyTypes = from elem in new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
                                                      let type = elem as ViewFamilyType
                                                      where type.ViewFamily == ViewFamily.Detail
                                                      select type;
        //uiDoc.Selection.SetElementIds(new List<ElementId>() { door.Id });
        var dim = door.get_BoundingBox(null);

        using (Transaction transaction = new Transaction(doc))
        {
            transaction.Start("Creating Detail View");
            BoundingBoxXYZ box = dim;
            var detailView = ViewSection.CreateDetail(doc,viewFamilyTypes.First().Id, box);

            detailView.Discipline = ViewDiscipline.Architectural;
            detailView.DetailLevel = ViewDetailLevel.Coarse;
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

I'm using Revit 2018,
Any help or suggestion is welcome just to finish my student research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do The Building Coder articles on [creating a section view](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.38) help?

Comment: Yes it dose. Thanks Jeremy, I just edited code on this link  [link](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/06/create-section-view-parallel-to-wall.html) and it's fine now. :)

Comment: great! glad to hear it helps!